# sort associative array in tcl

Tags: sorting, arraylist, tcl

I want to sort the array like this but can't find a way. Everyone help me!!!

I want to sort the array like this but can't find a way.
`L = {{55 746} {163 746} {163 778} {55 778}} {{939 746} {1047 746} {1047 778} {939 778}} {{277 746} {385 746} {385 778} {277 778}} {{721 746} {829 746} {829 778} {721 778}} {{1161 746} {1269 746} {1269 778} {1161 778}} {{1605 746} {1713 746} {1713 778} {1605 778}} {{499 746} {607 746} {607 778} {499 778}} {{1383 746} {1491 746} {1491 778} {1383 778}}`

Comment: What does your array look like?

Comment: like this: {{55 746} {163 746} {163 778} {55 778}} {{939 746} {1047 746} {1047 778} {939 778}} {{277 746} {385 746} {385 778} {277 778}} {{721 746} {829 746} {829 778} {721 778}} {{1161 746} {1269 746} {1269 778} {1161 778}} {{1605 746} {1713 746} {1713 778} {1605 778}} {{499 746} {607 746} {607 778} {499 778}} {{1383 746} {1491 746} {1491 778} {1383 778}}

Comment: You posted a list of lists {{a b} {c d}} {{e f} {g h}} ... nobody knows what you are trying to sort. Please improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

That *actually* looks like a list of lists of pairs. You normally sort those by passing a compound `-index` to `lsort`:

```
lsort -integer -index {0 0} $L
```

That won't overwrite the original variable; Tcl doesn't sort in place.

Comment: This is sorting by the first element of the first pair in each sublist. If you want something else, be *very* specific in your question what you want to get out.